# CSS on Material UI components

Tags: css, material-ui

I keep running into trouble in trying to use Material UI.

I have a Material UI table. I'm trying to centre align the text.

The Material UI standard CSS has an element called: MuiTableCell-root-60. That has a attribute with text-align: left. I can't find a way to override that setting. The table doesn't use an element with that name in an exposed way. I can't find a way to put a centre aligned selector on the table.

how do you modify standard Material UI CSS attributes?

I've tried various things, including adding centre align to the root selector, but it gets ignored.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
    textAlign: 'center',

  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700,
  },

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Overrides with Classes](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) section of the documentation will explain how you can override the behavior of the TableCell's root class.

Define your classes as you describe in your question and apply them to your component using `withStyles`:

```
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
```

This is a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that accepts a JSS object (or function returning such an object), adds the styles to the document, and supplies a `classes` prop to the wrapped component:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

The `classes` prop is an object that maps the class names defined in your JSS to the real class names in the document.

To center the text in a TableCell you want to override its `root` class.  Begin by defining the JSS that would do this, and pass it to `withStyles` so that you have a `classes` prop (as described above):

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  centered: {
    textAlign: 'center',    
  },
});
```

When rendering your TableCell, override the root class by specifying a `classes` prop and setting it to an object with the classes that should be overridden.  In this case, we're interested in changing the `root` class:

```js
const SimpleTable = ({ classes }) =>
  <Paper>
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
          <TableCell numeric>Protein (g)</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {data.map(n => {
          return (
            <TableRow key={n.id}>
              <TableCell classes={{ root: classes.centered }}>{n.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell numeric>{n.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </Paper>;
```

Attributes defined in the class specified for `root` will be overridden.

See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qx3j4j6llj) for a working example (and the full code).

Answer (score 0):

To override the inline-styles of the root element try to change TableRow Properties style, like this :

```
 const styles = {
  propContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
    margin: '0 auto',
  },
};
```

For more information visit this [website](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table)

Comment: Hi @Nani gord, thanks for trying to help. I found the answer and added it below. I hope it helps others who might be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is that you have to use the Material UI syntax for using classes.

It looks like this:

```
<p className={classes.amendbody}>
```

Then you define the const with an amendbody style, like this:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },


  amendbody: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: '1.6rem',
    fontWeight: '300',

  }

});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: My answer will help you understand how to override the default classes defined within Material-UI components so that you don't need to wrap the cell contents in a `p` tag.