# Overriding TableRow hover CSS on Material-ui in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Been going round in circles on this. Clearly I'm not fully understanding how class overrides work in Material-ui.

I tried this answer:
[CSS on Material UI components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125789/css-on-material-ui-components)
but it didn't work (no errors), perhaps because I'm using a stateful component rather than the stateless one in the example.

Currently I'm trying this...

```
<TableRow className={styles.tableRow}
    key={n.id} hover
    onClick={event => this.handleRowClick(event, n.id)}
    classes={{ 'hover': {color: '#7EA5FF'}}} >
      <TableCell>&nbsp;</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{n.title}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{n.author}</TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

But I get this error:
the key `hover` provided to the classes property is not valid for TableRow.
You need to provide a non empty string instead of: [object Object].

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the code you shared, you have

className={styles.tableRow}

then

classes={{ 'hover': {color: '#7EA5FF'}}

You should put your style modification in the declaration of styles.tableRow and delete the props className because it seems not be in the api. https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/

Something like:

```
const styles = theme => ({
     tableRow: {
      hover: {
         /// your styles...
        }
     }
});
....

render() {
 // I think you should use the props classes, because it's the name of 
 // the props to get the style from the function HOC withStyles of MUI
 const classes = this.props.classes;
 return (
   <TableRow
    classes={classes.tableRow}
    key={n.id} hover
    onClick={event => this.handleRowClick(event, n.id)}
>
      <TableCell>&nbsp;</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{n.title}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{n.author}</TableCell>
</TableRow>
 );
}
```

If you share all the code of your component in a sandbox or something like it I can help you more. I need to see your variable where you declare the style and I need to see how you pass it to the component.

It's because material-ui is based on JSS to style the component. It's a bit disturbing when you are not familiar with it.

Here is a good exemple for your case

https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/#customized-tables

And here is a good documentation about it too

https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes

Comment: Here is a quick exemple https://codesandbox.io/s/7946ojyr6 . Ask questions if you need a deeper understanding, it's hard for me to fully explain it in english without question from you

Comment: Ah! Now it's working. I was wondering what the use of css local rules were (the &:hover) and now I see how I was setting up the styles wrong. You're right, Material-ui styling is damn-right odd. I need to go and experiment with it, now I understand more. Thanks!

Comment: They have a really good documentation about it with concrete exemple, it helped me a lot, do not hesitate to take a look :) Happy to helped you ! Understand the concept of React HOC helped me too ! And read about the JSS presentation page helped me too ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  hover: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "green !important",
    },
  },
}));

 const classes = useStyles();
<TableRow hover classes={{hover: classes.hover,}}/>
```

Comment: I would recommend giving a bit more explanation than code, give a man a fish type thing

Answer (score 1):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
tableRow: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: '#7EA5FF'
    }
  }
}));

const classes = useStyles();

<TableRow hover className={classes.tableRow}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [withStyles](https://v4.mui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) (V4). It uses a HOC implementation.
Another example [here](https://v4.mui.com/components/tables/#customized-tables).

```
const StyledTableRow = withStyles((_) => ({
  root: {
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
   },
  },
}))(TableRow);
```

Then

```
<StyledTableRow>
   // Row logic goes here
</StyledTableRow>
```