# TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Get error from this, can't seem to figure out why this is undefined.

It was working previously, but once i put my const styles for table cell and it will throw undefined error for the fromDate.

Any guidance on how to troubleshoot this?

**Error thrown from the following**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fromDate: `${props.date.format('YYYY-MM')}-01T00:00:00.000Z`,
      toDate: `${props.date.format('YYYY-MM-') + props.date.daysInMonth()}T00:00:00.000Z`,
    };
  }
```

**Full details about the class component**

```
const styles = makeStyles({
  cell: {
    '& .MuiTableCell-root': {
      padding: '1px',
    },
  },
});

class Meetings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   ...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   ...
  }

  getMeetingsList = () => {
   ...
  }

  onMeetingTitleClick = (event, meetingId) => {
   ...
  };

  render() {
    const {
      meetings, loading,
    } = this.props;
    const getMeetings = meetings => (
      Object.keys(meetings).map(meetingDate => (
        <MeetingsCard
          key={shortid.generate()}
          onMeetingTitleClick={this.onMeetingTitleClick}
          meetingDate={meetingDate}
          dayMeetings={meetings[meetingDate]}
        />
      ))
    );
    const tableTemplate = ({ classes }) => (
      <PerfectScrollbar>
        <Paper style={{ borderRadius: 0, boxShadow: 'none', height: 500 }}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="left" classes={{ root: classes.cell }} style={{ width: 250, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Meeting Date</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left" style={{ width: 260, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Meeting Time</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left" style={{ width: 520, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Title</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left" style={{ width: 730, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Location</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <Table size="small">
            <TableBody>
              {getMeetings(meetings)}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Paper>
      </PerfectScrollbar>
    );
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary
    return (loading)
      ? <Skeleton page="Calendar" multiply={20} />
      : (!isEmpty(meetings)) ? tableTemplate() : <h1>No records found</h1>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  meetings: state.Meetings.meetings,
  loading: state.Meetings.meta.loading,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  getMeetingList,
}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, withStyles(styles))(Meetings);
```

Comment: Can u try this ?
`${props.date.format('YYYY-MM-') + props.date.daysInMonth()}T00:00:00.000Z`  =>  `${props.date.format('YYYY-MM-')  ${props.date.daysInMonth()}T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Which components constructor is that? Are you even passing date with props, if yes that might be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC `withStyles` is a material-ui HOC which means you should use it like this:

```js
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Meetings))
```

or split declaration to make it obvious:

```js
const MeetingsWithStyles = withStyles(styles)(Meetings);
const MeetingsConnected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MeetingsWithStyles);
export default MeetingsConnected;
```

Specifically, I think you get this error because third argument of connect is mergeProps. It is meant to merge ownProps (given by parents) and things you get from mapStateToProps & mapDispatchToProps before giving the result to the connected component as props. So if you don't return an object in it you get no props in the connected component.

By giving an unrelated function (the withStyles call result) in place of `mergeProps` you are messing your component props and it ends up with no props at all.

No props => no props.date => error when calling props.date.format in constructor

---

#### Edit

Another error you have here:

```js
const tableTemplate = ({ classes }) => (
```

`classes` is provided by withStyles in your component props, so extract it from `this.props` along with `meetings` and `loading` (and remove it from tableTemplate params):

```js
const {
  classes, meetings, loading,
} = this.props;
```

Comment: Yes, looks like u are right. Now I'm getting 
>>> The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(Meetings)> component:
Was trying to follow this stack overflow post but mine is using a class component 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125789/css-on-material-ui-components

Comment: I don't understand, which error do you get now ?

Comment: Ok I think I understand what was the other issue, check my edit section

Comment: Yeah think it caused another error (React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by WithStyles(MyMeetings). This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks:). But no worries. I will try to google more and post another question if i can't fix it. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

`format of undefined`

It clearly means your `props.date` is not defined. You should check the parent component from where it's being passed on and console.log to validate if a valid date is being passed on.

From my experience, I can say that this kind of error mainly occurs for some kind of typo.